# Cucumber ruby how to use ParameterType to transform given expression?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am trying to use `ParameterType` as `Transform` was removed in cucumber from version 3.0 I have the below feature with the step definition and parameter type. Is there any problem in my `ParameterType` as it is throwing error as follows:

Feature File:

```
Scenario: Learn how to write transformations
    When I print the date for today
```

Step Definition

```rb
When('I print the date for {today}') do |today|
  puts today
end
```

Here is the `ParameterType` am using:

```rb
ParameterType(
  name: 'today',
  regexp: /[\w]+/,
  transformer: Date.today
)
```

Error am getting:

```rb
When I print the date for date
features/wb_test.feature:11
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
c:\jruby-9.2.7.0\bin\cucumber:23:in `
'
if Gem.respond_to?(:activate_bin_path)
load Gem.activate_bin_path('cucumber', 'cucumber', version)
else
gem "cucumber", version
```

Please let me know if am doing anything wrong in the above steps.

Comment: I added an answer below with a fix for your code. The error you're actually seeing looks like it might not be code-related though. Maybe try what it says in this article? https://makandracards.com/makandra/43353-fix-rubygems-binary-error-undefined-method-activate_bin_path-for-gem-module-nomethoderror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code I get this error:

```
  Scenario: Learn how to write transformations
    When I print the date for today           
      wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
      ./features/support/parameter_types.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
      features/file.feature:15:in `When I print the date for today'
```

This indicates that the transformer needs to be a function. I got it to work by changing your `ParameterType` definition to:

```
ParameterType(
    name: 'today',
    regexp: /[\w]+/,
    transformer: ->(str) {Date.today}
)
```

Comment: I am glad to hear it!